# Specflow feature files in Visual studio 2013 express does not show color combinations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow, visual-studio-express

I'm using Specflow in Visual studio 2013 express and till now manged to install the specflow. But now when I'm writing fetaure files, they are shown with plain text colors. I've used cucumber in Java and there it shows different color for various keywords like - Given, When, Then, Scenario, etc.

I'm sure it should be similar in Specflow as well, can someone please help me understand why my feature files don't have these color codes and how to fix it ?

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio, and if you have, did you restart Visual Studio since installing the extension?

Comment: Yes, I did that Greg, I'm using express edition so not sure if that is a limitation with VS express.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently setup VS Professional 2017 with specflow. I had this issue initially and root cause is Visual studio doesn't know what's that specflow file. it is getting confused. simply because it is not finding the right plugin for that. I believe you have already installed the specflow plugin. I suggest uninstall that and reinstall (this seems silly but believe me it works sometimes). also make sure you are installing right version of specflow plugin for your visual studio version as there are quite a few out there. once installed, close VS and restart your computer and restart VS. These tricks worked for me so give it a go.